# Are small factories good practice?

Tags: php, unit-testing, factory

I have created

```
namespace factories;

use Upload\File;
use Upload\Storage\FileSystem;

class FileFactory
{
    private $fileSystem;

    public function __construct(FileSystem $fileSystem)
    {
        $this->fileSystem = $fileSystem;
    }

    public function create()
    {
        return new File('file', $this->fileSystem);
    }
}
```

File object is from this https://packagist.org/packages/codeguy/upload library.

I want to test my code which uses File and want to mock getMimeType for example.

Lets say I want to test that my function throws exception in this code:

```
$file = $this->fileFactory->create();

        $mimeType = $file->getMimetype();

        if (!in_array($mimeType, ['image/png', 'image/jpeg', 'image/jpg'])) {
            throw new ValidationException('File type is not supported. Use png, jpg.');
        }
```

So I would mock fileFactory, which retunrs mocked File.

It will work. But is this good? My colleague argued that there is too many abstractions when using such factories.

Another option is to just set data in $_FILES array, and do not mock the File object. Create it with new keyword.

So which is better?

Comment: I think this question is better suited for the software engineering site. SO is for questions regarding a specific implementation.

Comment: but I also showed specific implementation of factory. I could copy the content to that site, but is it good to have 2 copies?

Comment: @arielnmz when referring other sites, it is often helpful to point that [cross-posting is frowned upon](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-posting/info)